# SSIS Custom Destination Component - Send Row to OLE DB Destination

Tags: ssis, components, buffer, oledbconnection

I am building a custom SSIS destination component that reads an input, does a few minor things and sends it to an OLEDB connection.
I have an OLEDB connection called myconn and for the ProcessInput method I want to know the syntax for sending the row from the input to the myconn OLEDB connection.

```
public override void ProcessInput(int inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
{
            while (buffer.NextRow())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Some Code here to send the data from the input to the OLEDB data destination (i.e. myconn )
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            if (buffer.EndOfRowset)
            {
                myconn .Close();
            }
}
```

I always get a little lost with the ProcessInput method. I imagine it should only be a line of code or two?

Comment: When you say "send the row", do you mean insert it into a table in the connection?

Comment: Also, what version of SSIS are you using? They've changed how they handle reading buffer rows in 2012.

Comment: Yes, insert the data into the table in the connection. SSIS version is 2012.